# How to gracefully shutdown a Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is there any difference between [springapplication.registerShutdownhook()](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#registerShutdownHook--) () and [Springapplication.exit(applicationcontext)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#exit-org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext-org.springframework.boot.ExitCodeGenerator) ?  Will either of them also shut down the JVM gracefully?

Comment: the first registers a callback which will be called on exit, the second exits the application.

Comment: @Marged will any of them gracefully shutdown JVM also.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  In future, please improve your questions or include further information by editing them, rather than using comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a [ConfigurableApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html), you can use the method registerShutdownHook() to register a shutdown hook with the JVM runtime. You can see more here.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html?is-external=true#addShutdownHook-java.lang.Thread-

You use Springapplication.exit(applicationcontext) to close the application context an finish the Spring application.

Comment: if we close the application context and spring application, will it end the JVM also.

Comment: No necessarily, because your main method may be still running